# In jQuery, can I select multiple items with the same ID (in separate ASCX controls on the same ASPX page)?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have an ASPX page that has two instances of an ASCX control; the control has an asp:TextBox with ID of "TextView". I want to be able to access both of those controls' contents from within the ASPX page. However, when I use:

```
$("#TextView").each(function() { SomeOtherFunction(this.value); });
```

it only finds the first one.

Is there a selector that will find both of them?

Answer (score 0):

Hum, if you drop in such a user control, then each element from the user control "usually" winds up as a prefix.

So, in the user control, say a button, text box, or whatever?

Well, the markup and selector would as normal be the control.

Say a button in the user control:

```
 #cmdAddProject
```

But, rendering as user control, say I drop in this:

```
       <uc1:GPedit runat="server" id="GPedit3" 
            Title="Edit Project Choices"
            Col1="Project" 
            Col2="ProjectImage" 
            Heading1="Project" 
            Heading2="Image" DTable="Projects" />
```

So, the id of above user control is GPEdit3.

So, now a valid selector of that button in the user control would be this:

```
#GPedit3_cmdAddProject
```

So, you could just add a class to the control in question, say

```
 Class=zoo
```

Then select by that class perhaps???

I mean, hit f12 (browser debug tools), and choose selected elements, and see what the control ID has become.

In theory, a web page is not allowed to have more then one control with the same ID, and quite sure when using jQuery selector, you only get the first one anyway.

so, in that user control, I have a label with id = "lblHead"

So, you have to select by id, and above would with above user control become:

```
$('#GPEdit3_lblHead').
```

I mean, think of the reverse problem, how to select a control from a given user control? We need that ability.

You can get jQuery to select by suffix.

So, for above?

```
$('[id$="_lblHead"]')
```

The above will run a bit slow, as noted, adding a class to the control, and selecting by class would work better.